# I can not create a react-native project?

Tags: react-native

PS D:\reactnative> expo init  Mobileapp
expo : File C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information,
see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- expo init  Mobileapp
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Comment: be carefull about wich terminal you use ... does not work with powershell on VSCode

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't given powershell the proper privileges to execute the expo powershell script. To verify, run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in powershell. If it prints `Restricted`, then you haven't enable powershell to run scripts, which is why you are getting that error.

I'm not sure of what's the proper execution policy to have, but base on the link your error provided, then `RemoteSigned` is the one you want. Open powershell as an administrator and set it with

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
```